# Get-Random increased randomness HELP Powershell

Tags: powershell, random

I am in need of a little help as to increasing the randomness of get-random thus not repeating so often.

I have been using this with powershell:

```
$formats =
@("*.mpg")
$dir = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
gci "$dir\*" -include $formats | Get-Random -Count 1 |
Invoke-Item
```

My application is to have a in home virtual television channel that randomly selects 1 file from multiple folders at 6am and plays them all day until midnight, powers off and starts up, repeating the process daily.  The problem I am finding is that whatever the get-random command uses had a tendency to choose the exact same file often.  Thus after months of running this script, I am seeing the exact same movies chosen day after day and some that are never chosen. I'm guessing because the get-random is using the clock as it's factor for choosing a number?

Is there a way to increase the odds of getting a broader selection of files .mpg's in this instance and less of a repeat of the same .mpg's chosen?

My other option was to find a script that would keep track of the .mpg's chosen and "mark" them, or sort by date accessed and not play the same file twice, until all files of a particular folder have been played once; then "unmarking" all the files and starting over.  To me that sounds like advanced scripting that I just don't have the knowledge to procure on my own.

Any insight into my dilemma would be vastly appreciated.  Any questions about my specifics to help you ascertain a conclusion to this query will be forthcoming.

**maybe i want to know how to increase the random distribution?  I'm looking for a way to have more variety in the files chosen day after day and less repeats.

Comment: How many mpg files are you selecting amongst?

Comment: If you take influence on the selection of random numbers, you are **decreasing** the randomness.

Comment: Each folder contains 50-100 mpgs.  There are some that seem to repeat daily, or a few times per week and some that have never played at all in months.  From what I can tell.

Comment: maybe i want to know how to increase the random distribution?  I'm looking for a way to have more variety in the files chosen day after day and less repeats.

Answer (score 0):

that (access time) should be fairly easy to check

```
$item = gci "$dir\*" -include $formats | where {$_.lastaccesstime -le (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)} | 
  Get-Random -Count 1
$item.LastAccessTime = Get-Date
$item | Invoke-Item
```

Comment: Note that by default `LastAccessTime` update on read is disabled for performance reason.

Comment: which os? i'm using w10 and it is on by default

Comment: Does `fsutil behavior query DisableLastAccess` print `DisableLastAccess = 0` for you?

Comment: it does display 1, oh, I assume for me it displays lastwritetime

Comment: all running this script does for me is open program files x86 folder

Comment: maybe i want to know how to increase the random distribution?  I'm looking for a way to have more variety in the files chosen day after day and less repeats.

Comment: well, for that you can use `-setseed` and implement some sort of hashing to randomize a seed properly